# How to bootstrap in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

The following is my main.ts file in which i performing bootstrapping............

```
    import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {Component, OnInit, provide,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {ToastOptions} from "ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr";
import {PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy, Location} from '@angular/common';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
import { UrlPathWithParams } from '@angular/router';
import { Config } from './components/headers';
import { TagInputComponent } from "ng2-tag-input";
declare var System: any,jQuery:any;
@Component(
    {
        selector: 'demo-app',
        templateUrl: './demo-app.html',
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
        //providers:[UrlPathWithParams]
    })
    class MyDemoApp {
    name: string;
    classmap: string;
    elementRef: ElementRef;

    constructor(public location: Location,elementRef: ElementRef,private router:Router) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }

bootstrap(MyDemoApp, [      
    provideForms(),
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,Config,
    provide(ToastOptions, { useValue: new ToastOptions(options) }),
]);
```

but abgular2/moment(https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) is bootstarpped in the following way,

```
import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MomentModule
  ]
})
```

When i tried to include moment to my project,i didnt have the ngModule in my main.ts,so how can i do that.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: I am using rc.4

Comment: `NgModule` was introduce with `RC.5` and became mandatory with `RC.6`.  You should update to final (2.0.1)

Comment: Therefore i cant use the following bootstrapping method for using any of the  plugins that has to import in @NgModule{()}

Comment: Can go with the comand 'npm update --save'  to update my version

Comment: Is this a question? I don't know this stuff well because I'm using Dart myself.

Comment: @nlr_p Follow this doc : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html and update your Angular version as Gunter Suggested